# Temperature readings with DS18B20 work with Arduino Yun and Mega 2560 but not with Arduino Giga

Tags: arduino

Three temperature sensors type DS18B20 are connected to pin D7. The power supply of the sensors is done through GND and +5V pins of the Arduino board. The sensors are thus used in a normal mode, not in parasite mode.

The code below is used to get the temperature data and works perfectly on Arduino Yun and Arduino Mega 2560.

```cpp
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// DS18B20 Sensors at D7 (Mega 2560)
OneWire bus(7);
DallasTemperature sensors(&bus);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Start the temperature measurement on all sensors and wait for it
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  // Make string for assembling the data to Serial log
  String dataString = "";

  int index = 0;
  DeviceAddress addr;

  while(sensors.getAddress(addr, index)) {
    // Read and show the result
    dataString += String(index);
    dataString += " = ";  
    dataString += String(sensors.getTempC(addr));
    dataString += " ";  
    // Next index
    index++;
  }

  // Print the data log
  Serial.println(dataString);
  
  // Wait one second before reading the next values
  delay(1000);
}
```

Unfortunately, when using the same code on Arduino Giga, everything goes well until just after the code is uploaded to the Arduino Giga. MbedOS crashes apparently immediately since the onboard LED is flashing red as described [here](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/7991505987612-If-an-LED-on-GIGA-R1-WiFi-is-flashing-red). All wiring is the same as with the Arduino Mega 2560 and Arduino Yun. No other pins except the one for the sensor (GND, +5V and D7) are in use for this test.
FYI: I need the Arduino Giga because I need a lot of pins for other sensors and a built in WiFi.

I followed the instructions. Pressing once on the RST button doesn't help, the light immediately starts flashing red again.
Pressing twice on the RST button makes is possible to upload the same or different code to Arduino Giga but doesn't solve the problem.

Could someone explain why this is happening on Arduino Giga and not on Arduino Mega 2560 and Arduino Yun? What might be a solution to use the DS18B20 on Arduino Giga?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to do some debugging yourself to see if it was caused by the incompatibility of the two libraries with the Arduino Giga. If you comment out all the code inside setup() and loop(), and only leave the two "includes" and the creation of the bus and sensors instances, compile and upload the code, will it still crash?

Comment: @hcheung: I followed your instructions. When setup() and loop() are commented out completely, there is no red light flashing any more. In setup() only Serial.begin(9600); is present. The first line in the loop() which is sensors.requestTemperatures() gives the red light error on Arduino. FYI libraries included are:#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

Answer (score 0):

The library is incompatible due to new processor. Use microDS18B20 library. This worked for me on Giga R1.

You can find it on github (i don't know if I'm allowed post links here)

Comment: Its a bit more complex because when multiple sensors are on one pin you have to get their addresses first (you have to mount them one by one on the pin to get the addresses) but his library works perfectly indeed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as mentioned in the question. My temp DS18B20 probe worked on my arduino uno but not on the giga r1. I installed the microDS18B20 library and everything is working great now.

It is kind of hard to read the documentation since its in another language but I just copied it into google translate and was able to make out what was needed.

Thanks @user21783323 for sharing this library

Comment: This is not an answer, rather a comment for a different answer. Please consider posting as a comment for that answer, or using the upvote if you found that answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have just managed to resolve this issue by substituiting `utils` folder from OneWire library (version 2.3.7) with the one from GitHub, which is updated to work with mbed OS.

It seems the issues was in the `OneWire::reset()` function called from `DallasTemperature::begin()`.
Indeed, as soon as `noInterrupts()` is called, the Arduino GIGA R1 crashes.